# How to add custom buttons to notification panels

Tags: java, android, notifications

So I've been looking around but I hav'nt found a definitive answer on if its possible to make custom buttons on the notification panel. If its possible how would you do this? If you arn't sure what I mean by the notification panel, heres an example.[NOTIFICATION PANEL EXAMPLE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWCiN.jpg)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#tile_api

Comment: Thank you, I've been looking for days haha. I wasn't exactly sure what they where called eather.

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/quick-settings-tiles-e3c22daf93a8
and
http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/quick-settings-tile-api-example-in-android-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer found from the comments - example:

Inside of **<application>**

```
    <service
        android:name=".TileServ"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:label="TEST"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

TileServ.java file

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.service.quicksettings.TileService;
import android.widget.Toast;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class TileServ extends TileService {

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onTileAdded(){
    super.onTileAdded();
}

@Override
public void onTileRemoved(){
    super.onTileRemoved();
}

@Override
public void onStartListening(){
    super.onStartListening();
}

@Override
public void onStopListening(){
    super.onStopListening();
}

@Override
public void onClick(){
    super.onClick();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```